# How to consume restful wcf service in java?

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, rest

I have a .net restful wcf service .
I want to know how can i consume in java.
Kindly,help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what technology is used to implement the REST based service, assuming it is using HTTP, from a Java client you should use something like http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/

Comment: i am getting exception near DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); it says:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient, method: createHttpParams signature: ()Lorg/apache/http/params/HttpParams;) Incompatible argument to function

Comment: @user596548  So create a new question with tags Java and HttpClient and post your code. I'm sure someone will be able to help.